# Receiving a "no module named xlwings" error on Mac when calling the Python script within XLS but not direclty

Tags: python, excel, import, python-module, xlwings

Using the "fibonnaci" example that is provided by Zoomer Analytics, I'm unable to run it directly within Excel as it returns a "no module named" error seen in this screen capture:

[image: named module error]

Yet, if I were to call the fibonnaci.py directly, it would work.  I'm on a MBP workstation, Yosemite with Python 2.7.9.

Comment: They're probably using different installs of python.

Comment: And how is the module installed? What Python executable is used for both cases? What is the current working directory in both cases, or `sys.path`?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, your comment coupled with Felix's answered led me to my `sys.path` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlwings currently only loads the `.bash_profile`, so another solution would be to add the path of your interpreter to your `.bash_profile` file by adding this line: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. This will enable you to go with the default settings in the xlwings VBA module.

What might be happen on your side is that you may have defined the location of your default python installation (python.org?) in a file like `.bashrc` or `.profile` and since xlwings doesn't load them, it goes against the system installation of python where xlwings is missing.

Comment: Ah, this was it.  So, I didn't have `.bashrc` or `.profile` set in my home directory but I decided to print `sys.path` and, coupled with your answer, led me to the problem.  Excel is using the System's (Mac) version of Python but I pip'd `xlwings` into my "homebrew" instance of Python so both didn't line up.  Chalk it up to not enough sleep.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the intended behavior but modifying the `xlwings.bas` file to hard-code the `PYTHON_MAC` variable to `PYTHON_MAC = "/usr/local/bin"` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: xlwings from VBA *should* be using your standard Python installation. If you type `which python` in a terminal prompt, what do you get?

Comment: The path that I used in my answer is what received when I typed `which python `.  I don't have anything in my bash profile overriding that.

Comment: Hm - OK interesting... and when you do `$ python` and then `>>> import xlwings` it works without problems?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings

python setup.py install

```
 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```